# Google Docs Import XML Returning Comment

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to get the US Population from this webpage: [Link](http://www.census.gov/popclock/print.php?component=counter)

Here it is in the HTML:

```
<div id="us-pop-container">
<h3>U.S. Population</h3>
<!-- population counter -->
<p>316,434,526</p>
</div>
```

What I want is the **316,434,526**, which is the population. (but it changes)

Here is the xpath:

```
//*[@id="us-pop-container"]/p
```

When I put it into Google Docs, it returns nothing. However, if I put:

```
//*[@id="us-pop-container"]
```

it returns the comment, "population counter". **How do I return the population number?**

---

Here is my full spreadsheet:

**A1**:

```
http://www.census.gov/popclock/print.php?component=counter
```

**A2**:

```
//*[@id="us-pop-container"]
```

**A3**:

```
=ImportXML(A1,A2)
```

Comment: Your problem is that that data isn't in that location in the html file; it's added later by javascript. If you use show source, rather than inspecting the DOM, you'll see what the importxml function has to work with; the `<p>` you're looking at is empty at that stage. The good news is the number you want is in the file, the bad news is it's buried in a pile of javascript and JSON, which I don't imagine is going to be fun to try to parse in a spreadsheet. Good luck! :)

Comment: @WillGoring I traced through the page to find it gets it's data from [this page](http://www.census.gov/popclock/data/population/us). I can parse through it. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA("http://www.census.gov/popclock/data/population.php/us")),"population:(.*)population_rate")
```